# Static variable in the scope of a Java rest service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have an APIController class defined with a `@RestController` annotation, which holds several REST services, defined with the `@RequestMapping` annotation.

I'm looking for a way to define a "static" integer which will be initialized to 0 on every REST call.

My goal is to define a singleton with a scope of a REST instance / call, and not with the scope of the entire application.

For example: I have a `getData` REST, which calls the internal function `getSingletonData` twice. First call to `getSingletonData` will return 1 and the second will return 2.

Once another user will call the `getData` rest service, the same function `getSingletonData` will return again 1 and 2, and not 3 and 4 (which will happen in case the internal integer variable will be defined as static?).

I know I can just define the variable as a local variable inside the REST service, but I want to avoid passing it as a parameter to many functions, and I would like the class to be a singleton (the class just returns sequential numbers whenever asked, in the scope of that specific REST call).

Comment: this value `getSingletonData` is unique for each user? why don't you keep it in the database?

Comment: It's even more unique than that - it's unique per REST request. Regarding saving it in the database - If possible, I would like to avoid redundant roundtrips to the database just to fetch this sequence number.

Answer (score 3):

Well, one way to solve your problem is by defining a request-based bean. You see, Spring components may have different [scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html): e.g. singleton, prototype, request, and session.

So, you could define a bean whose scope is the "request" itself. By doing this you'd get a fresh instance of it injected per request in e.g. your controller.

You could define such a data provider somewhat as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class DataProviderConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST,
            proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public Supplier<Integer> getRequestDataProvider() {
        AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger();
        return value::incrementAndGet;
    }

}
```

And then in your controller, you would get an instance of it injected per request using classical injection.

```
@RestController
public class DataProviderController {

    @Autowired
    private Supplier<Integer> requestDataProvider;

    @GetMapping("/answers")
    public Integer[] getAnswer() {
        return new Integer[]{requestDataProvider.get(), requestDataProvider.get()};
    }

}
```

And this will consistently produce the result `[1,2]` per every request, which seems to be what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to implement this solution but it seems the configuration class isn't really loaded ("class DataProviderConfiguration is never used"). Anything else might be missing?

Comment: @TomShir I just tried my example and worked just fine. The information you  provide is not enough to draw any conclusions on why it does not work for you. You'll have to figure it out yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Tried to just use the function in one of my classes, with the request scope, but it always returns the same number. Does setting the scope as a request scope gets `value` to keep its value during the request and increment it every time? If so, it didn't work :(

Comment: @TomShir If I were you, I would start [here](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fourth-edition).